# How do I accept credit card payments inside a C# app?

Tags: c#, credit-card

How do I accept credit card payments inside a C# app? I'll use some textboxes for the inputs but what gateway do I contact to complete the transaction? I don't mind working with any service, paid or free.

Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Payment Service Providers/Gateways generally provide their own APIs/SDKs in various development languages.

You can also purchase libraries that have already integrated to many of these to help implement your solution quickly or run multiple payment options. eg: http://www.dotnetcharge.com/

With regards security, in our experience, it makes sense to integrate in such a way that you pass the user over to the 3rd party provider for processing rather than take or store credit card details within your own system.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout Paypal, Authorize.net, Google Checkout, and any of a number of other merchants out there.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Sample Code for IP Commerce at GitHub: https://github.com/ipcommerce

Note: You will need to create a project at https://my.ipcommerce.com in order to get access to the sandbox environment.

Full Disclosure:  I work for IP Commerce and among many other things, we provide the fastest way to connect to processors like Chase Paymentech, Vantiv, First Data, etc.  We also provide a tokenization service that will take the card-storage burden off of your application, eliminating your PCI Compliance.